# JQuery Mobile - Number of Rows in ListView

Tags: jquery, listview

Is there a way to know how many rows a Jquery ListView has?

Thanks

Comment: Please put some more effort into your questions. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `$('.ui-listview').children().length;` should do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var listViewSize = $("#myListView").find("listitem").length+1;
```

Comment: This answer is as bad as the question. shame on you for trying to get first post